# logout script works on localhost but not on my hosted server

Tags: php, session

The weirdest thing is happening, when I logout of my app it redirects me to the correct page, so the script runs. However when I randomly type in a page that I should not have access to since my sessions and cookies have been destroyed I have access to it, this only happens on my hosted server, on local host it works fine, has anyone run into this before?

The start sessions script

```
<?php
 session_start();
 // If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with a cookie
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
           if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_email'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $_COOKIE['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['lawyer_client'] = $_COOKIE['lawyer_client'];
            }
       }
  ?>
```

The log out script

```
<?php
// If the user is logged in, delete the session vars to log them out
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
// Delete the session vars by clearing the $_SESSION array
$_SESSION = array();

// Delete the session cookie by setting its expiration to an hour ago (3600)
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 7600);
}

// Destroy the session
session_unset();
session_destroy();


// Delete the user ID and username cookies by setting their expirations to an hour   ago   (3600)
setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 7600);
setcookie('user_email', '', time() - 7600);
setcookie('lawyer_client', '', time() - 7600);

// Redirect to the home page
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .    '/index.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);}
?>
```

I am checking to see if the session is set using this script

```
require_once('startsession.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
echo '<p class="login">Please <a href="main_login.php">log in</a> to access this page.</p>';
exit();
}
```

So after looking at what I just put down my first guess would be that my logout script is not properly clearing my sessions...but why is it only not doing it on my shared host?

Comment: I just removed the part of logout that deletes the cookies and I am not getting the same result for both, is it possible that for some reason my shared hosting account is not letting me set the cookie time back two hours to delete them?

Comment: To make this easier do I even really need to set cookies if I am using sessions?

Comment: No need. For your requirement, I believe you need either session or cookie, but not both

Comment: Also I doubt whether your setcookie call in logout works, because it just reqirects after setcookie call, to set a cookie, you need to pass some data to the browser followed by setcookie I believe. I am not 100% sure

Comment: I am going to see what happens if I get rid of my cookies, I am 67% certain that is my problem......well....that and being too cheap to use a host that uses the same version of php I wrote this thing in...let that be a lesson to everyone

Comment: @SajithNair you were correct, I was not clearing my cookies correctly, in the end it was easier just to use sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some shared hosts you will have to include the sessions directory in order to work. Are you sure that the sessions are correctly initialized?